# Can 2300 watt washing machine burn out wiring in my house?

Tags: electrical, wiring, washing-machine

My standard voltage is 230 V and the socket is 16 A. I am asking the question because I had a 1500 watt water heating rod connected with another 15A socket which did burn out my home wires after a week of use.

Comment: What does "burn out" mean? If your home is fitted with proper circuit breakers or fuses the wiring is protected. Please revise to explain better what your specific concern is and to tell us about your wiring.

Comment: Can you provide photos of the burnout you had with the 1500W water heater? That should be *well* within the capability of a 16A/230V socket

Comment: @isherwood, When I was using the 1500 watt heating rod, I just heard some small sound of wire or socket blast from inside. I think either my socket was blown out or the wires that were connected to that socket burned out.

Answer (score 2):

Your socket and wiring (if properly installed/rated) are good for 3,680 Watts (230V X 16A.) As such a 2300W device should be perfectly fine.

### However:

If a 1500W device "burned out the wires" on a 15A 230V (3,450W) socket, either the wiring in question was improper/defective, or there were other things also connected to those wires. In any case, somehting was wrong if the wires burned out rather than a circuit breaker (or fuse) tripping (or blowing.)

So your wiring installation may be improper or defective - it is at least suspect, and should be checked by a qualified electrician to identify and correct any dangerous deficiencies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, easily if the house wiring is faulty or defective.

Get it all checked by a competant registered electrician.